# How to override storefront ui file in VSF 1 for magento 2.2.4 framework

Tags: vue.js, overriding, magento2

I am working on VSF 1 with Magento 2. I just want to move the navigation bar from the header for the capybara theme. I installed the capybara theme from https://github.com/vuestorefront/vsf-capybara

I want to move the navigation bar beneath the logo and search as shown in the image. Want to move to red section area.

[image]

I tried to move the navigation template from header file `\vue-storefront\src\themes\capybara\components\organisms\o-header.vue` but it's not working.

```
   <template #navigation>
    <SfHeaderNavigationItem
      v-for="category in categories"
      :key="category.id"
      @mouseover="isHoveredMenu = true"
      @mouseleave="isHoveredMenu = false"
      @click="isHoveredMenu = false"
    >
      <router-link
        :class="{active: isCategoryActive(category)}"
        :to="categoryLink(category)"
      >
        {{ category.name }}
      </router-link>
      <MMenu
        :visible="isHoveredMenu && !isSearchPanelVisible"
        :categories-ids="category.children_data"
        :title="category.name"
        @close="isHoveredMenu = false"
      />
    </SfHeaderNavigationItem>
  </template>
```

I think it's coming from storefront-ui from file `node_modules\@storefront-ui\vue\src\components\organisms\SfHeader\SfHeader.vue`

If we can override this file and move sections, then It will work. Anyone has any idea how to override this file and modify ?

```
<slot name="logo" v-bind="{ logo, title }">
      <SfLink link="/">
        <SfImage
          v-if="logo"
          :src="logo"
          :alt="title"
          class="sf-header__logo"
        />
        <h1 v-else class="sf-header__title">{{ title }}</h1>
      </SfLink>
    </slot>
    <div class="sf-header__aside">
      <!-- @slot Use this slot for language or currency selector -->
      <slot name="aside" />
    </div>
```